# memory usage reading pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have some problems while reading file even from txt or HDF5 formats to dataframes in pandas because a txt file of about 200 mb of strings stored as txt and read with read_table causes a memory consumption of about 600 Mb. If I append the dataframe to HDFStore the file is about 200 mb too. Here is how I read the file

```
datatypes=[('FIELD1','S13'),('FIELD2','S3'),('FIELD3','S31')]
df=pd.read_table('c:\\folder1\\example1.txt',sep='|',dtype=datatypes)
```

Is there a way to read the txt file more efficiently in terms of memory usage?

I'm using pandas v 0.11.0

Thank you in advance

Comment: How do you measure memory consumption? And are you really just using the two lines above?

Comment: I just watch at OS process monitor . I ommitted the import pandas as pd and futher instructions not related with the text file import task.

Comment: don't specify the dtypes, these cause the data to be read as fixed type strings rather than variable length object types

Comment: I also saw the same issue while loading the csv file and almost same factor of expansion. Though problem is posted 3 years back, I can't find any solution to it. I down-sampled my csv file, so that I can work with it. If you would use simple file read write operation (without using pandas), it doesn't consume much memory (that is how I down-sampled it)